# Android Geofece Exit/Enter in geofence Events not triggerring

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-api-client, android-geofence

I am stuk with this issue for more than a week.Goefence events not triggering on entering or existing the Geofence. i have tested it several times on emulater.

**Here is my MainActivity**

**

```
package com.example.internet.ytgeofence;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = null;
    protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    private Context mContext ;
    Button startLocationMonitoring, startGeofenceMonitoring,     stopGeofenceMonitoring;
    TextView t;
    public List<Geofence> listGeofence;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    /*int resultCode =
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.
                    isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);*/
    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
    startLocationMonitoring = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    startGeofenceMonitoring = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    stopGeofenceMonitoring = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mContext=getApplicationContext();

    startLocationMonitoring.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StartLocationMonitoring();
        }
    });
    startGeofenceMonitoring.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StartGeofenceMonitoring();
        }
    });
    stopGeofenceMonitoring.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StopGeofenceMonitoring();
        }
    });

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Connected to google Api Client");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "suspended connection to google Api Client");
                    }
                })
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to connect to google api client" + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
                    }
            }).build();


    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1234);
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.d(TAG, "On start Called");
    Toast.makeText(this,"On start called" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.reconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "On stop Called");
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "On Resume Called");
    super.onResume();
    int response = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (response != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Paly Services not avaliable.show dialouge to download");
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, response, 1).show();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Paly Services avaliable");
    }
}

private void StartLocationMonitoring() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location Monitoring Start");
    try {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setInterval(10000)
                .setFastestInterval(5000).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                t.setText("Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + "Lng" + location.getLongitude());
                Log.d(TAG, "Location Lat/Lng" + location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
            }
        });


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception in location Monitoring" + ex.toString());
    }

}

private void StartGeofenceMonitoring() {


    Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder().setRequestId("SAN Loaction")
            .setCircularRegion(48.848016, 2.346888, 200)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE).setNotificationResponsiveness(1000)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT).build();
    mGeofenceList.add(geofence);


    GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = getGeofencingRequest();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeofenceService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    try {


    if (!googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google API Client Not Connected");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                ,"Google api client not connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } else {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(googleApiClient, geofencingRequest, pendingIntent).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess())
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Geofence added Successfully");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Geo fence added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Failed to add Geofence"+status.getStatus());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Geofence not added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
        });


    }
    }catch (SecurityException ex)
    {
        Log.d(TAG," Security Exception in api client");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Geofence not added successfully"+ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
private void StopGeofenceMonitoring(){
    Log.d(TAG,"Stop geofence called");
    ArrayList<String> geofenceids=new ArrayList<String>();
    geofenceids.add("SAN Loaction");
    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(googleApiClient,geofenceids);
}
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Inside Getgeofencing request");
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

}
```

**The Activity_main.xaml is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.internet.ytgeofence.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:text="Start Location Monitoring" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Start Geofence Monitoring" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Stop Geofence Monitoring" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
    android:text="Status" />
```

**The GeofenceService is**
    package com.example.internet.ytgeofence;

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

import java.util.List;

public class GeofenceService extends IntentService {

public static final String TAG="GeofenceService";

public GeofenceService() {

    super(TAG);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Inside Service",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG,"Inside Service Constructer");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Inside IntentHandler");
    GeofencingEvent event=GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if(event.hasError())
    {

    }
    else
    {
        int transition=event.getGeofenceTransition();
        List<Geofence> geofences=event.getTriggeringGeofences();
        Geofence geofence=geofences.get(0);
        String RequestID=geofence.getRequestId();
        if(transition==Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Entering Geofence Area"+RequestID);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Entering Geofence Area",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        else if(transition==Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Exiting Geofence Area"+RequestID);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Exiting Geofence Area",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }


}
```

}

**And the Manifest.xaml is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.internet.ytgeofence">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".GeofenceService"/>
</application>
```

Any Help is Highly Apperciated.

Comment: How does the location change using an emulator? How did you check exactly? How do you simulate entering a geofence?

Comment: if you are using emulator then set the location of emulator as per your choice that you want to detect. If it still causes issue then GPS  feature might be not working in emulator , give a try of actual device with enabled location permission.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine just use real device, and enable GPS, also give app location permission, that set, I use emulater before it's not worked with me.

**Update**

I try your code, there is some point to fix this issue, first add this code in manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!-- add this -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
```

in your service remove Toast and use log just because it's crashing app, this is the result 
[image]

I add `GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT` for `GeofencingRequest` just to ensure it will work perfectly

```
    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Inside Getgeofencing request");
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}
```

in the manifest I add this permission -I think you already add it, put just in case- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

Comment: Keep in mind that Google's Geofence API doesn't just use GPS, it relies heavily on Network locations in order to keep power drain low. Emulators allow for GPS injection, but not really for Network points. That said, I highly recommend using a real device for testing geofences, and using emulators to test the logic the geofence should trigger.

Comment: i test this app with my real device. but not working. How can i strict it to use only GPS Location.

Comment: I test it in my device and update my answer with my fixes, I wish it works with you.

Comment: 3zcs Can you please tell me where do I add this code?

Comment: @atishr on the top of each snippet there is the file name of the code

Comment: Where you calling getGeofencingRequest() method later ?? or is it callback method

Comment: In addition to the above answer, if that was not a typo error, I noticed that you have two if conditions for one transition event. Change the second to transition==Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT